# String comparison Algorithms

Tags: string-comparison, information-retrieval

In one of my assignments I got a question like this.

Study and implement the following unsupervised string comparison algorithms. Use them to measure the similarity between the sentence pairs in the data set. **Use the training set to tune the algorithm parameters whenever necessary.**

```
Jaccard coefficient
Levenshtein distance
Jaro distance
```

These are the algorithms I got.

Also I have given part of the data I got as the training dataset

```
TOPIC ||| TWEET_SENT_1 ||| TWEET_SENT_2 ||| HAVE_SIMILAR_MEANING

Kriss Kross ||| The Mack Daddy of Kriss Kross ||| RIP former Kriss Kross member Chris Kelly ||| False

Body Party ||| I liked that video body party ||| that damn body party song is stuck in my head ||| False

Corey Brewer ||| Second of all What the hell is Corey Brewer doing ||| Corey Brewer needs to go Dleague ||| True
```

**Can someone please let me know what it means by tuning the algorithm parameters.**

I'm bit confused with this.

Comment: They may be wanting you to put weights on the result of each algorithm to produce a weighted average of the distance scores. The training set would then be used to arrive at an optimal set of weights eg `0.5 * Jaccard + 0.4 * Levenshtein + 0.1 * Jaro`. The parameters would then be these weights. `HAVE_SIMILAR_MEANING` is the metric used to refine the weights, `True` being good and `False` being bad. The set of weights which produced more True matches would be favoured.

Comment: Hi John.... I feel like this asks to tune algorithms separately.. for an example if Jaccard is considered, is there a special approach to tune it?

Comment: I wasn't aware of any parameters for the normal Jaccard distance. Do you have the pseudo code or documentation for the Jaccard distance algorithm you need to use?